# The Torah scrolls written by Jewish kings

Tags: history, sefer-torah, malchut-royalty

The Torah commanded Jewish kings to write their own Torah scroll from a master in the possession of the Levites, and to read it every day of their life so that they should not become haughty and so they might keep G-d's laws.  Deut. 17:18-20.  Given that many of Israel's and Judea's kings were not G-d-fearing, do we know how many kings actually wrote a Torah scroll and where they were stored before the first exile?  Was the practice revived in the Second Temple?

Comment: Are you referring to the first or second Torah which might have been an amulet.

Comment: Why would you think that they didn't keep this Mitzva during the 2nd Temple?

Comment: There were no Jewish kings (descended from King David)  during the second temple.