# How much of the sefer torah did the king read each day?

Tags: halacha, history, sefer-torah, malchut-royalty

According to [D'varim 17:18-20](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0517.htm), a king was required to write for himself a sefer torah and read from it each day ( וְקָרָא בוֹ כָּל-יְמֵי חַיָּיו).  This doesn't say he had to read the *whole* sefer each day (it doesn't say *kol*), which also seems like it would be impractical.

What did he read?  Did he read it sequentially over time, for example following a daily parsha division?  Were there certain parts he was to read every day?  Did he just choose something each day?  And how much was he to read -- a single verse, a minimum number of verses, a large amount?

(Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/28507/472).)

Comment: Interesting. My first inclination would be to assume that this is like the general mitzva of learning Torah, for which measurements are not defined. I'll bet [*Sefer Hachiunuch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch) addresses this.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I think I'd always just assumed that too, but the use of וְקָרָא made me wonder.  It doesn't say learn or even study; it says read.

Comment: Note Mechon Mamre renders כל ימיו as "all of his days" not "each of his days". The former lends itself more to a less formal interpretation IMO.

Comment: @DoubleAA, oh, good point.  I think I've seen *kol* rendered both ways; I wonder which is more supportable (or maybe it depends on context?).

Comment: Next source worth checking (and I'll leave this to someone else, at least for now): Rambam in Sefer Hamitzvot and in Hilchot Melachim.

Comment: @IsaacMoses both negative.

Comment: _Minchas Chinuch_ also negative. Other _mone hamitzvos_ (_mitzva_ listers)?

Comment: See the fourth section of [this article](http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/salt-devarim/48-8shoftim.htm), which brings 5 different interpretations about the type of Torah scroll from which the king would read (the possibilities listed are the full Torah, sefer D'varim, the particular section in Shoftim, the Aseres HaDibros, or a summary of all the commandments).

Comment: @DoubleAA and msh210, do you mean "negative" as in "not addressed" or as in "indicates that there's no rule"?

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I meant it doesn't really address reading and implies there's no rule of how much to.

Comment: @Fred, if any of the sources it cites discuss reading, then you have the makings of an answer.

Comment: @Fred Shalom, I know your comment is from 7yrs ago but what exactly did the article say and could you find another source similar?  Your comment was exactly what I was seeking when researching this question.

Comment: @יהודה It looks like the original link is no longer working, but there is a link to an archived version of the page [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20080517042319/http://www.vbm-torah.org/archive/salt-devarim/48-8shoftim.htm). The relevant parts are the third and fourth sections of the page.

Comment: @Fred Todah Rabbah beloved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[*Sefer Hachiunuch*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch) doesn't list the reading/learning as its own commandment. Instead, part of his definition of the commandment for the king to write a Torah scroll, [Commandment #494](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40631&st=&pgnum=607), includes "so that it will always be with him, and he'll read from it." He does not, however, specify how frequently or extensively the king is to read from it.

He further specifies that an intent behind this commandment is that the king is given power to wage war, execute people, etc., which is unchecked by any other person, so it's necessary for him to constantly inspire himself to check his own behavior by looking at his Torah scroll. He derives from guidelines given in the Talmud in Tractate Sanhedrin that this Torah scroll should "not be away from his eyes at any time except when he's using the bathroom."

So, it seems that the Torah scroll is meant to be there for constant inspiration (just by its presence) and for ready, frequent reference, but there's no particular rule regarding how frequently or extensively the king is supposed to read from it.